# PDF to Image in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, pdf, ionic-framework, ionic3, pdf.js

I am new to ionic

I want to convert my .pdf file to image in ionic.

After searching i found **pdf.js** is javascript library which does the same.
http://usefulangle.com/post/24/pdf-to-jpeg-png-with-pdfjs

Same i want to achieve using ionic, What i want to do is i have .pdf located inside my **/asset** folder i want to convert this to image. For this i have added **pdf.js** file inside my ionic app also imported **pdf.js** in **index.html**

Now i how do i use it to convert pdf to image??

***Please help and thanks in advance!***

Comment: Why is converting the PDF to an image on the mobile device important? What is wrong with the PDF itself? You lose any vector and text data in the PDF when you switch to an image.

Comment: Its a requirement and problem is solved. followed this tutorial http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/index.html#interactive-examples might help someone